# Facebook Graph API- bypass privacy warning modal?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Built an application that uploads videos to a users timeline.

The first time they use the app and log in to their facebook account they are presented with a 2nd facebook Privacy modal.

```
<appname> would like to access your public profile, friend list and photos
```

Is there a way to somewho bypass this modal by changing the facebook application security settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: no.

This is the basic scope that is [implicitly added](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/public-profile-and-friend-list/) by Facebook to your request. Each scope has to be approved by the user. There is no way to programmatically or configurably skip this dialog on your side.